# How to set variables for java

Tags: java

On ubuntu 14, i have the same problem : when i run android studio, java packages are not find.

I need to do export command ?

```
export PATH=${PATH}:"/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java"
```

it's do nothing more.

Comment: screen : http://i.imgur.com/Ro9B8N3.png

Answer (score 1):

You are able to launch Android Studio, which indicates that you're fine on the Java front.

Android Studio itself, however, may have trouble finding the Android SDK.  You need to create a file called `local.properties` and place it in the root of your project, with contents like this

```
sdk.dir=/home/jodii/programs/androisdkfolder
```

After that, Gradle should read your `build.gradle` file and install the missing libraries.

Comment: i put this file in /home/jodii/ ?

Comment: (Answer updated) put `local.properties` in the root of your project folder. Point that `sdk.dir` line at your Android SDK folder

Comment: I have already this file, automatically created :

## This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
#
#Fri Apr 18 17:52:12 CEST 2014
sdk.dir=/home/fred/appli/android-studio/sdk